# AudioKit 4.1 Mach-O Linker Error Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4, audiokit

I am trying to follow a basic tutorial using AudioKit 4.1. I first imported the AudioKit framework in the project as shown in the image below.

[image]

After importing the AudioKit framework, I added a few lines of code in the ViewController as follows:

```
import UIKit
import AudioKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let oscillator = AKOscillator()
    oscillator.amplitude = 0.1
    AudioKit.output = oscillator
    oscillator.start()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Upon running the code, I got 59 error as shown in the image below. How do you fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since version 4.1, AudioKit is now shipped as a static framework. Because of all the internal C++ code, it depends on the standard C++ library. This dependency used to be resolved automatically by the dynamic linker, but not any more.

The easiest way to make these errors go away is to simply add the `-lstdc++` linker flag in your target settings in Xcode (under "Other Linker Flags").

Comment: As a note: this is documented in the [instructions on GitHub](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/master/Frameworks/README.md).

Comment: Note to the note :) Documentation mentions "-lc++" which didn´t work for me. Only adding "-lstdc++" did the job for me.